# retrieve actual sent time of an received sms in android

Tags: android, time, sms

In the original SMS app of android i can check the details of a received sms and it wil show me the time and date it was sent by the sender and the time i received this message.
I am interested in the time difference between these 2

I can get the time i received the sms via this code. how can i extend this so that i also get the time it was sent?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                    .toString();
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))
                    .toString();
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))
                    .toString();
            Date smsDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));
            String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"))
                    .toString();
```